# Integrate Azure AD for user Authentication and store data on user's one-drive using REST API

Tags: java, office365, onedrive, adal, azure-ad-graph-api

I wanted to integrate Azure AD service with my web application to authenticate the users and store the document to user's one-drive location.

I have tried adal4j library sample where I configured my app on azure portal and able to authenticate the same. But now I need to use Microsoft Graph APIs for using one-drive service (uploading files).

Any suggestions from you guys?. I checked Graph APIs where Java samples are not available.

I have tried below library.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/samples/active-directory-java-webapp-openidconnect/

Also refered below link where I didn't found any samples for Java.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/?view=odsp-graph-online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to make an onedrive Graph API call using Java.

The ADAL4J library that you are referring to has a wiki that shows how to use it.

The wiki for the ADAL4J github library shows you how to get an access token and make a call to the Microsoft Graph is here : https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java/wiki/ADAL4J-Basics

Excerpt Below :

> Here are the steps to get started with ADAL4J:
>
> Instantiate the ADAL AuthenticationContext object.
>
> String authority =
>   "https://login.microsoftonline.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/";
>   ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
>
> AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(authority,
>   true, service); Use the authentication context instance to acquire
>   tokens. ADAL4J provides different methods to acquire tokens based on
>   your application type. Refer the acquire tokens section for the
>   appropriate method for your implementation.
>
> Use the acquired token as a bearer token in the call to the web API.
>
> Future future =
>   context.acquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(code, redirectUri, new
>   ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret), null, null);
>   AuthenticationResult result = future.get();
>
> HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
>   conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " +
>   result.getAccessToken()); You can also refer this full sample of a web
>   app using ADAL4J to authenticate users and get tokens for the MS Graph
>   API.

Once you have an access token you would follow the getting started guide for the OneDrive Graph API here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/?view=odsp-graph-online

Excerpt below:

> 1. User authentication and authorizing your app Microsoft Graph and OneDrive API use OAuth 2.0 for authorization. By completing an OAuth
>      flow, your app receives an access token that provides access to the
>      Microsoft Graph a particular set of permissions for a user.
>
> Your app provides the access token in each request, through an HTTP
>   header:
>
> Authorization: bearer {token}
>
> For more information on authorizing your application and obtaining an
>   access token, see App authorization with Microsoft Graph.
>
> 2. Make calls to a resource Once your app is authorized and received an access token, it can make requests to the Microsoft Graph endpoint
>      for OneDrive or SharePoint resources. To construct the URL for a
>      resource, you need to know the relative URL for the root resource
>      (like a user, group, or site) and the drive resource or driveItem
>      resource your request is targeting.
>
> A request URL includes these components:
>
> Microsoft Graph root URL and version
>   (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0) A root resource target
>   (/users/{id}) A OneDrive API resource target (/drive or
>   /drives/{id}/items/{item-id} or /drive/root:/path/to/item) Note:
>   Throughout the documentation, only partial syntax such as: GET
>   /drive/items/{item-id} is used for the sake of brevity. Prefix the
>   path with the correct root URL and root resource target in order to
>   obtain the full resource path or URL.

Please leave a comment if you have anymore questions.